# Android - Align view center to left of other view

Tags: android

[image]

i want to use ConstraintLayout to do this, but i dont know how to do it...

edit:
Thank you for your answer. Now I have found a solution, and the code is as follows

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/textView"
```

But why can't this problem be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple. Align both left and right to the left of the referred view, then it becomes align center to the left of the referred view.

```
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/textView"
```